# How to interchange the fqdn <-> hostname in hosts file

Tags: sed

I am trying to update the format in `/etc/hosts` file.
sample

```
# more /etc/hosts

14.5.10.13 host1 host1.mydomain.com
14.5.10.14 host2 host2.mydomain.com
#
```

to

```
14.5.10.13 host1.mydomain.com host1
14.5.10.14 host2.mydomain.com host2
```

I tried this but didnt worked. Please suggest.

```
#sed 's/host{1,2} /host{1,2}.mydomain.com/' /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To swap the second and third fields in the file hosts but only if the second is `host1` or `host2`:

```
$ awk '$2~/^host[12]$/{a=$2; $2=$3; $3=a} 1' hosts
# more /etc/hosts

14.5.10.13 host1.mydomain.com host1
14.5.10.14 host2.mydomain.com host2
#
```

Here, `$2~/^host[12]$/` selects only those lines whose second field matches one of the hosts of interest.  For those lines, the second and third field are swapped.  The final `1` is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

To do something similar with sed:

```
$ sed -E '/ host[12] /{s/ (host[12]) ([[:alnum:].]*)/ \2 \1/}' hosts
# more /etc/hosts

14.5.10.13 host1.mydomain.com host1
14.5.10.14 host2.mydomain.com host2
#
```

Here, `/ host[12] /` selects only those lines that contain `host1` or `host2` surrounded by spaces.  For those lines, `host1` or `host2` is swapped with the word that follows.